# logic problem in the Equal Stacks algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Algorightm details: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal-stacks/problem

Overall, we have three stacks of cylinders, each cylinders has the same diameter and we need to find out the maximum possible height where the three stacks are exact the same height.

The height is calculated by the sum of the stack elements, for example:

Sample input:

```
5 3 4
3 2 1 1 1
4 3 2
1 1 4 1
```

The stacks have 5, 3, and 4 cylinders and the respective heights of those cylinders are given on the next lines.

Expected output:

```
5
```

My programm output:

```
7
```

My logic to return the maxium possible height:

```
function equalStacks(h1, h2, h3) {
    let sum1 = h1.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
    let sum2 = h2.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
    let sum3 = h3.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
    let minHeight = Math.min(sum1, sum2, sum3)
        
    while (!(sum1 == sum2 && sum2 == sum3)){    
        if(minHeight == 0) return 0
            
        if(sum1 > minHeight){
            sum1 -= h1.pop()
        }
        
        if(sum2 > minHeight){
            sum2 -= h2.pop()
        }
        
        if(sum3 > minHeight){
            sum3 -= h3.pop()
        }
        
        minHeight = Math.min(sum1, sum2, sum3)
        
        if(sum1 == sum2 && sum2 == sum3) return sum1
    }
}
```

I started by summing all the values of the arrays and determining which one was the smallest, because if it's equal to 0, the maximum height is 0.

I initialize a while loop where the condition for iteration is that the sum of the stacks must be different.

If the minimum height is 0, then 0 is the compatible maximum height.

Then, I check if any stack is above the minimum height; if it is, I remove an element from the stack and decrease the total height.

Finally, I update the value of the minimum height for the next iteration and check if the heights are equal. If they are, I return the height and finish the program.

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing the inputs in reverse. Your answer, 7, would be correct if all the stacks were upside-down.

In the test case, the inputs are:

```
3
2     1
1  4  1
1  3  4
1  2  1
```

And the best solution is 5:

```
2      
1      
1  3  4
1  2  1
```

If the inputs were flipped:

```
1
1     1
1  2  4
2  3  1
3  4  1
```

Then the best solution would be 7:

```
1     1
1     4
2  3  1
3  4  1
```